# How to open file loaded via REPL in prolog?

Tags: prolog, prolog-toplevel

In prolog, or at least in SWI-Prolog, you can load a file typing

```
[filename].
```

or

```
['filename.ext'].
```

or

```
[path/to/file].
```

or

```
['path/to/file.ext'].
```

However, I want to preprocess the file going to be loaded and therefore I need the content of above singleton lists to be a compatible file path, using it as first argument of [`open/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=open/3). What currently works:

1. The hook to catch queries from REPL using [`expand_query/4`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=expand_query/4)
2. Matching for singleton list expressions and binding the one element to a variable

What works not:

- Using the in »2.« mentioned variable as `+SrcDest` for `open/3`.

So how can I process the quasi-path to a real path, such that any of the 4 above mentioned ways to load a module works?

Comment: Check the documentation of the `absolute_file_name/3` predicates at http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=absolute_file_name/3

Comment: @PauloMoura Using `extensions(['.pl'])` as option to `absolute_file_name/3` works great – all four cases are handled this way.